# fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting the error

```
fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory
```

when i'm trying

> catkin_make

here is my CPP code

```
 //this progamme publishes randomly-genarated velosity messages for turtlesim
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h" //for geometry_msgs::Twist
#include "stdlib.h" // for rand() and RAND_MAX

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  
  //initialize the ROS system and become a node.
  ros::init(argc, argv, "publish_velocity");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  //Create a publisher object.
  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("turtle1/cmd_vel", 1000);

  //seed the random number genarator
  srand(timeO(0));

  //Loop at 2Hz until the node is shut down
  ros::Rate rate(2);
  while(ros::ok()){
    
    //The other four fields, set default to 0
    geomatry_msgs::Twist msg;
    msg.linear.x = double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX);
    msg.angular.z = 2*double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX)-1 ;
    
    //publish the message
    pub.publish(msg);

    //Send a message to rosout with the details.
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Sending random Velocity command:" <<" Linear = " <<msg.linear.x <<" Angular = " <<msg.angular.z);

    //wait till next iteration
    rate.sleep();
    }
  }
```

And here is my CMakelist file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(velocity)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp geometry_msgs)

catkin_package()

include_directories(include${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})


add_executable(vel pubvel.cpp)


target_link_libraries(vel ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

and here is the package.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>velocity</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The velocity package</description>

  <maintainer email="aklinahs@todo.todo">aklinahs</maintainer>

  <license>TODO</license>

  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>geometry_msgs</exec_depend>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>


  <export>

  </export>
</package>
```

what could be the wrong here,....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300839/fatal-error:-ros/ros.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Aklinahs](https://answers.ros.org/users/37027/aklinahs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-08-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-17**:\

> please help me....

Please don't add these sort of things to questions.

We already know you're looking for help, otherwise you wouldn't be posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> include_directories(include${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
> ```

This is missing a space between `include` and `${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aklinahs](https://answers.ros.org/users/37027/aklinahs/) on 2018-08-17**:
Thanks it worked , thanks a lot (y)